# Removing folder in Ruby under a path

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I would like to be able to remove the folder "OLDFOLDER" and its sub folder in the following folder structure via a ruby script in linux (Im pretty new to ruby and Linux).

```
/X/Y/Z/OLDFOLDER/SUBFOLDERS
```

I know there are ways to remove folders in ruby, for example:

```
removeOldFolder = "rm /X/Y/Z/OLDFOLDER/"
    `#{removeOldFolder}`
```

but i am not sure how to remove folders like the structure i have above,

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [FileUtils](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) rather than system calls to commands like this.

A better way of doing this:

```
FileUtils.rm_rf("/X/Y/Z/OLDFOLDER/")
```

Do be **extremely** careful when executing `rm -rf` on arbitrary locations.